# How to integrate a wizard into a BPMN process

Tags: wizard, bpmn, business-process

The current project I work on I shall model a business process (as they call it) with BPMN. The user interface is mostly completed. It's a web fronted based on AngularJS. There is also a wizard which should be used for user interaction during the business process. In my humble opinion every page of that wizard could be assigned to a single user task (bpmn).

*Unexpectedly* the wizard should behave like a wizard. There are buttons for the next and previous page and modal dialogs and a finish button. I'm worry about whether that behavior will work together with a bpmn engine or not if I model user tasks per wizard page.

Question:

1. Would you model a wizard with BPMN?
2. Should this BPMN be a runnable BPMN or traditionally implemented (e.g. plain AngularJS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would model this wizard using BPMN task only if each wizard "pages" are actually independent tasks. For example if each task can potentially be performed by different users I think that make sense to model that as a sequence of BPMN task.

If a single user go through all the wizard quickly I would suggest to implement all the logic in AngularJS.

Comment: Nice. That's the same thought I had but because I'm new to BPMN I was a little uncertain about it.

Answer (score 0):

No. One task per role/swimlane, not a string-of-pearls within the same swimlane. A major point of using a structured process is getting handovers right and here there are none. Also, the performance will be bad.